# How to hidden and show fields and custom validate form with Jquery in YII2

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii2

I have a form in which they appear fields for one type of entry, otherwise these fields are hidden, at the time this code to hide and show fields is active, the validation that exist in these fields does not work, what it is wrong?

```
$('#cadastro-tipoinscricao_codigo').change(function(){
if($('#cadastro-tipoinscricao_codigo').val()==1){
   $('#empresa_form').hide();
}else{
   $('#empresa_form').show();
}
```

The code in jquery to hide and show fields is working, but when he is on the validation of the custom field does not work!
The fields can only be compulsory if the type of application is code 2.3 or 4:

```
       [['nomeempresa','cnpj','emailempresa','telefonefixoempresa','telefonecelularempresa', 'enderecoempresa', 'bairroempresa', 'cidadeempresa', 'estadoempresa', 'cepempresa'], 'required', 'when' => function ($model) {
            return $model->tipoinscricao_codigo == 2;
        }, 'whenClient' => "function (attribute, value) {
            return $('#tipoinscricao_codigo').val() == 2;
        }"],
```

Comment: The code is simpler as `$('#cadastro-tipoinscricao_codigo').change(function(){
   $('#empresa_form').toggle(this.value!=1);
});` but unless you show us the HTML and some more script - for example where you assign the event handler, we cannot help you more

Comment: Hello code to hide and display the fields works, what does not work is the validation, at the time this jquery is active following the validation in model get values.

Comment: Please update your original question with formatted code - I believe that hidden fields are not and need not be validated as long as you empty them when hidden

Comment: Ok the question was edited.